# HttpWebRequest + GetResponseStream encoding

Tags: c#

How I can decode HTTP stream response?

I get this error message:

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type TEST.RootObject '�YL�' contains invalid UTF8 bytes.
```

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(UrlRequest) as HttpWebRequest;
            //request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "utf-8"); // I cannot get this to work!

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
                }

                DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());

                //// I cannot get this to work!
                //using (Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                //{
                //    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //    reader.ReadToEnd();

                //}
                //// test
```

Comment: It looks like you have some kind of compression, maybe GZIP. If you look on the HTTP headers it should tell you...Telerik's Fiddler is a good free tool for doing this.

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040641/there-was-an-error-deserializing-the-object-of-type-rd-details-%C3%AF-%C2%BD19-95-per-pe